# Twitter Bootstrap CSS static-fluid form positioning

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using the Twitter Bootstrap framework trying to get a layout like this:

[image: Desired layout]

This is how it looks now:

[image: Current layout]

[jsFiddle fullscreen](https://jsfiddle.net/flackend/YxKfc/show)

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/flackend/YxKfc/)

The width of the form container changes based on the width of the browser (Twitter Bootstrap's CSS media-queries). The icon-boxes always have 14px of width.

I've tried different things based on static-width-sidebar/fluid-content CSS layouts to try to make the text input width fill out.

I think my only option is making my own CSS media-queries that define an absolute width for the text input.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <section class="span9">
            <h2>Our Theme</h2>
            <p>lorem ipsum...</p>
        </section>
        <div class="span3">
            <section class="patch-well">
                <h2>Contact Us</h2>
                <p>Send a message......lorem ipsum...</p>
                <form>
                    <fieldset class="control-group">                        
                        <div class="input-prepend">
                            <span class="add-on">
                                <i class="icon-user"></i>
                            </span><input type="text">
                        </div>
                        <div class="input-prepend">
                            <span class="add-on">
                                <i class="icon-envelope"></i>
                            </span><input type="text">
                        </div>
                        <textarea></textarea>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Send message</button>
                    </fieldset>
                </form>
            </section>
        </div>
    </div><!-- row -->
</div>
```

```
@import url('http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/css/bootstrap.css');
@import url('http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/css/bootstrap-responsive.css');

body { padding: 10px }

.patch-well {
  color: #FFF;
  background: url('http://subtlepatterns.com/patterns/darkdenim3.png') repeat;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;

  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;

  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000;
}

.input-prepend {

}

.input-prepend .add-on {

}

.input-prepend input {

}
```

Comment: Answered a similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11190697/1478467). At some point responsive is useless and you should fix sizes (at least min sizes). Better to have a page to scroll than an input with 2 letters. IMHO fluid+`min-width` is your best option.

Comment: Check the min-width of the controls. they seem to have stopped resizing but the container continues to shrink.

Answer (score 2):

You put whole form into span3, it's about 25% of row width. Therefore, if resolution is big, span3 is not enough to contain whole form. On smaller resolutions, width of span3 becomes 100%, and on small resolutions looking good. Just use some other span class, and carefuly carefully calculate numbers in span classes. [Like here](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html) Also, i prefer to use row-fluid class instead of row class, it's easier to manipulate with width.

Always use structure like this

```
<div class="row-fluid">
  <div class"span3">
     <!-- content1 -->
  </div>
  <div class"span9">
     <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span6">
           <!-- content2 -->
        </div
        <div class="span6">
           <!-- content3 -->
        </div
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Note that always if i want new line in design without floating, and if i want 100% of width od parent element, i will use row-fluid. Because children elements can be again span elements the sum of the 12. In this example, "content1" will use 25% of width in big resolutions but in small resolutions it will have 100% width. In big resolutions, "content2" and "content3" will have 100% of parents width, but that is 75% of container width. In small resolutions, all span classes will have 100% width. If you don't want that in some cases, just override default bootstrap css with yours classes.

I hope you are understand what is my point. Sorry for my english :)

Answer (score 1):

This is what you want http://jsfiddle.net/YxKfc/14/, Please check it.

Answer (score 0):

As with many CSS frameworks you have to be very careful with **`padding`**. Take this off

```css
.patch-well {
  padding: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

bootstrap also allows you to simulate minimum widths for objects by not requiring you to make the entire layout fluid. In your case, you can try making the wrapper span and row for that nav not be fluid.