# Twitter Bootstrap: Stop input field extending beyond well

Tags: forms, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I'm having trouble trying to resolve this issue. The docs say that I should set the span equal to the parent span, however, it extends to the right outside of the well container when I do that. It looks fine when viewed on mobile (extends the appropriate amount to the right, filling the well), however, it doesn't play well on desktop (I want the fields to extend inside the well).

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span4 offset4">
            <div id="login-panel">
                <div class="well bordered clearfix">
                    <div class="text-center">
                        <div class="page-header" style="border-bottom: none; margin: 0;">
                            <img src="library/img/logo-01.png"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <form method="POST" action="#" accept-charset="UTF-8" class="pull-left">
                        <legend>App name</legend>
                        <div class="control-group ">
                            <!-- username field -->
                            <div class="controls">
                                <label>Email</label>
                                <input class="span4" type="text" name="email" value="" id="email" placeholder="Your email address">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="control-group">
                            <label>Password</label>
                            <!-- password field -->
                            <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password">
                        </div>
                        <div class="control-group ">
                            <p>
                                <input class="btn btn-default pull-left" type="submit" value="Sign-up">
                                <input class="btn btn-primary pull-right" type="submit" value="Login">
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div> <!-- end row -->
</div> <!-- end container -->
```

Comment: Use max-width: 100% on the input fields as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11855086/why-do-my-twitter-bootstrap-form-fields-overflow-their-well-using-fluid-containe

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Docs are actually saying:

> Use **`.span1`** to **`.span12`** for inputs that match the same sizes of the grid
>   columns.

But you want to make a full-width `<input>`, right?

### Make an `<input>` to take full width

```
input.full-width {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
}
```

Also remove `.pull-left` from the `<form>`. See how it woks on [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pMU2F/).

---

#### Edit

Since Bootstrap 2.2.0 use bundled `input-block-level` class to achieve this effect.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem recently with form and panel body. Upon inspection I noticed that the problem wasn't the inputs, but rather the form itself was extending beyond the panel. I fixed it by putting a max-width: 100% on the form instead of the input.