# twitter bootstrap input prepend full width

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Currently using  bootstrap-2.1.1

I have a `row-fluid` that contains 2 columns and inside those columns I have input-prepends. Here is a sample code:

```
<div class="row-fluid">
   <div class="span6">
      <ul>
         <li>
            <div class="input-prepend box-shadow">
                <span class="add-on">email</span>
                <input type="text" name="email" value="" placeholder="Edit email"/>
            </div>
        </li>
     </ul>
   </div>
   <div class="span6">
      <ul>
         <li>
             <div class="input-prepend box-shadow">
               <span class="add-on">name</span>
               <input type="text" name="name" value="" placeholder="Edit name"/>
             </div>
         </li>

      </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

YOU CAN SEE THE JSBIN HERE: http://jsbin.com/unuruh/1/

**PROBLEM**

How can I make the input fields full width (and that resize with browser) of the parent `input-prepend` using **preferable only CSS**? Keep in mind that the `add-on` should be the same width...

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: if your question is answered, please mark it!

Answer (score 8):

#### Fluid spans

Here is an approach : [Demo (jsbin)](http://jsbin.com/unuruh/4)

```html
<li>
  <div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="input-prepend box-shadow clearfix" style="border-radius: 3px;">
     <span class="add-on span2" style="width: 14.2%;float: left;">email</span>
     <input class="span1" style="width: 85.8%;float: left;border-right: 0;border-tradius: 0;border-bottom-right-radius: 0;" type="text" name="#" value="#hello" placeholder="Edit project"/>
   </div>
  </div>
</li>
```

The `width` and `float` are there to override what the responsive behavior is doing to `span`s, the rest of the inline style is to make the box a little bit prettier.

There is a similar question, without all the wrapper problems : [Fluid input-append in Bootstrap Responsive](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11188964/1478467)

---

#### Absolute positioning

**Update** version 2.3 : you need `.input-fullwidth { display: block; }`, [Updated Demo (jsfiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/Sherbrow/RmM2J/8/)

Another approach would be with absolute positioning : [Demo (jsfiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/Sherbrow/RmM2J/)

```css
.input-prepend.input-fullwidth {
    position: relative;
}
.input-prepend.input-fullwidth .add-on {
    width: 40px;
}
.input-prepend.input-fullwidth .input-wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    left: 51px; /* 40 + 2*5 - 1 */
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
.input-prepend.input-fullwidth .input-wrapper input {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
     -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
          box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="input-prepend input-fullwidth">
    <span class="add-on">email</span>
    <div class="input-wrapper"><input type="text" name="#" value="#hello" placeholder="Edit project"/></div>
</div>
```

---

Ultimately, you may be looking for the [flexbox feature of CSS3 (w3.org)](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-flexbox/)

Comment: I thought about that, but the designer wants the `add-on` to be fixed width...any other ideas?

Comment: @denislexic Just added an alternative. If you can, try the flexbox

Comment: Thank you, @Sherbrow. Your 2nd method worked very well for me.

Comment: Just wanted to update this because I used the 2nd solution but then when I upgraded to Bootstrap 2.3.1 it didn't work. The only change you need to make to your CSS for it to work in Bootstrap 2.3.1 is adding `display:block;` to your `input-fullwidth` class. That's it! Hope this helps someone else. Share the knowledge!

Comment: @Sherbrow can you make a jsfiddle for input-append also?

Comment: @marcushatchenson Have you tried inverting left and right [?](http://jsfiddle.net/Sherbrow/RmM2J/74/)

Comment: i can't vote yet, but the solution by Sherbrow works great:
version 2.3 : you need .input-fullwidth { display: block; } You need to get the css for input-fullwidth