# Full width input-append search button

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How do I make this search form full width like the button below it?

[image: Example]

```
<form class="form-search">
  <div class="input-append">
    <input type="text" class="input-small search-query">
    <button type="submit" class="btn">Search</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Can you show us the CSS you're using now?

Comment: No css. Default styles with twitter bootstrap 2.2.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Done

http://jsfiddle.net/MgcDU/6033/

Using approach from here:

http://boulderinformationservices.wordpress.com/2011/02/02/input-field-and-submit-button-on-the-same-line-full-width/

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div style="width:100%;background-color:#d0d0d0;text-align:center;">Example of a Full row</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span12 pull-right">
            <form class="form-inline">
                <button type="submit" class="btn" style="float:right;">Button</button>
                <div style="overflow: hidden; padding-right: .3em;">
                    <input style="height:1.6em;width:100%" type="text" placeholder="full width minus button width" />
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm not seeing any full-width input in that fiddle actually!

Comment: Thanks for pointing out Bertuz, the original cdns had mismatched versions, with the new version somehow not giving pull-right 100% width on a separate div. I've fixed both issues.

Comment: Sorry, but this is no solution for the problem! The left side of the button has rounded edges, but we need a straight left side with hard corners,...

see
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11188964/fluid-input-append-in-bootstrap-responsive

or
https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/6414

Answer (score 0):

Make the .input-append have a specific width then give your .search-query a width of 100% and your .btn a width of 100%

This is the best We can do without more details - like the CSS that is controlling this or an example of what you are doing on the page.