# twitter bootstrap variable width for input-append

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I can set the input's width to vary by putting it inside a .row and then assigning the desired .span#. How do I achieve the same effect but with an input-append?

```
<div class='container-fluid'>
  <div class='row-fluid'>
    <div class='span3 well'>
      <ul class='nav nav-list nav-stacked'>
        <li>
          <div class='input-append'>
            <input type='text'>
            <button class='btn btn-info' type='button'>Add</button>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class='span9'>
      <span>More stuff</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'll set the "Add" button's width to a fixed value via CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[See other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11188964/fluid-input-append-in-bootstrap-responsive)

```
function sizing() {
var formfilterswidth=$("#formfilters").width();
$("#msisdn").width((formfilterswidth-46)+"px");
}
$(document).ready(sizing);
$(window).resize(sizing);​
```