# input-prepend in Bootstrap responsive grid

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, user-interface

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span6 well">
        <div class="clearfix control-group">
            <div class="input input-prepend">
                <label class="add-on"><input type="checkbox" /></label>
                <input class="input-small" type="text" placeholder="Cost"/>
            </div>
        </div>                                      
    </div>

    <div class="span6 well">
            <div class="clearfix control-group">
                <div class="input input-prepend">
                    <label class="add-on"><input type="checkbox" /></label>
                    <input class="input-small" type="text" placeholder="Cost Range"/>
                </div>
            </div>                                      
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Looks good when windows is maximized.
[image]

When window-size is reduced.

[image]

Need help with re-sizing the input text with window-size.

entire form: [myForm](http://pastebin.com/FFqjCgtW)

Comment: Try the suggestions here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11188964/fluid-input-append-in-bootstrap-responsive

Comment: @parzival: i did try those before. Didnt help

Answer (score 0):

```
<label class="add-on span1"><input type="checkbox" /></label>
<input class="input-small span11" type="text" placeholder="Cost Range"/>
```

add classes like this on label and input .. similarly you can add class on control-group also.. and can vary the width by using span1- span12 or span*

in case if it still creates problem wrap control group in a row..

Comment: remove the input-small class from input and you have override the bootstrap -responsive by creating a separate class to control the width on mobile view . as responsive css now overrides the span classes. so write a seperate one to control the width..which override the responsive

Answer (score 0):

I'm wondering if there could be an issue with your CSS or any customising you have done. Taking your exact html above and the default Bootstrap CSS, everything looks good to me:

[Live view](http://www.bootply.com/render/64139)

[Edit](http://www.bootply.com/64139)

Good luck!

**EDIT**
The root cause is that as the viewport narrows, there isn't enought space to display cost and cost range input blocks in the space you have given them.

As an illustration, [check out this variation](http://www.bootply.com/64234) where I have added more width to the right hand column. The result is somewhat better, though not perfect.

Why not show the cost and cost range inputs on different lines?

Comment: this is s small part of my form. I will put the entire code in a pastebin.

Comment: I am just trying things! Also if you see the checkbox becomes really big when window size is small.