# simple form and input width error in bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I've created extremely simple form that contains 2 inputs and 2 buttons.
When I would like my form to take 6 spans width and be centered.

Below is my code:

```
<div class="container-fluid padded">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <!--filtry-->
                <div class="span6 offset3 padded" style="border: 1px solid black;">
                    <form action="#" method="get" class="form-horizontal">
                        <fieldset>
                            <div class="control-group">
                                <label class="control-label">Data od</label>
                                <div class="controls">
                                    <input type="text" id="dataOd" class="input-xlarge" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="control-group">
                                <label class="control-label">Data do</label>
                                <div class="controls">
                                    <input type="text" id="dataDo" class="input-xlarge" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-actions">
                                <div class="pull-right"> 
                                   <a class="btn wczytaj" href="#"><i class="icon-play icon-white"></i>Wczytaj</a>
                                   <a class="btn btn-info disabled eksportuj" href="#" id="eksportuj"><i class="icon-download-alt icon-white"></i>Eksportuj</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </fieldset>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My form in full size browser looks like this:
[image]

but after resizing it I get this result:
[image]

How should I change my code to get those input 100% width on every resolution?
Is there any simple way or do I must tweak whole bootstrap?

I've tried adding span* classes to inputs but without any luck.
There are similar questions on SO (https://stackoverflow.com/a/11193864/965722), but answer involves JavaScript and I would like to avoid that.

Here is jsfiddle with my code: http://jsfiddle.net/Misiu/HdSEn/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to increase the width of the span. Set span8 instead of span6.

Demo : jsfiddle.net/HdSEn/3

OR

If you want display full width of the box on page, add span12 instead of span6

jsfiddle.net/HdSEn/5/

**Updated**

```
 <div class="span7 offset3 padded well">
```

The problem is, form is greater than span7. Like form width> span7,6,5,4.... So you need to set width for input box.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/HdSEn/18

Comment: I'm bit confused. Standard grid has 12 columns. I want my box centered and half of width (6 spans), so it should be span6 offset3? Please correct me here

Comment: See. you using `span6 + offset3` in same class. So what actually happening here is its should take `margin-left: 330px and width: 570px`. If you want border for that division you should use 6+3=9 `span9`. I hope you understood. or if you want that `span6` in center of the page, use should remove that offset3.

Comment: I've changed my markup just a bit: http://jsfiddle.net/Misiu/HdSEn/8/ I was adding border only to visually see size of my container. If I change classes to `span8 offset2` my div is nicely centered, but If change classes to `span6 offset3` of `span4 offset4` input are getting out. Can You help with that too?

Comment: why because of your `form` width is greater than span7. Like `form width> span7,6,5,4...`. So you need to set width for input box. http://jsfiddle.net/HdSEn/18/

Answer (score 0):

Hope this solves your issue:

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cgirish/HdSEn/4/)**

**CSS**:

```
input[type="text"] {
    min-height:30px;
    width:100%;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```